# How connect to an existing Azure SQL database with Azure function using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am a beginner in Azure and I'd like to make connection between an existing Âzure SQL database and an Azure function (timer triggered) using Entity Framework Core.

I've seen so many videos and I've tried so many things, but I really couldn't get it done. If you have any ideas, could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's always useful to show what you tried so others won't come with the same suggestions or can see why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

1. package

```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.15" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.15">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.11" />
```

2. Define DBcontext

```
        public class BloggingContext : DbContext
        {
           
            public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
          

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
            => options.UseSqlServer("<connection string>");
         }

        public class Blog
        {
            public int BlogId { get; set; }
            public string Url { get; set; }

            
        }
```

3. function code

```
 [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            using (var db = new BloggingContext())
            {
                log.LogInformation("Inserting a new blog");
                db.Blogs.Add(new Blog { Url = "http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet" });
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

4. ExecuteEF Core Migration

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

5. Test

[image]
[image]